# Tinymce: How can I set the visible of my button via code?

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce-4

Hi I have 5 butttons in my toolbar. All these buttons are invisible. 
Now I want to show these buttons via code.
Is that possible?

Here is one example:

```
editor.addButton('ds_format_edit_1', {
    text: 'F1',
    tooltip: 'Formatvorlage 1',
    visible: false,
    onclick: function () {
        editor.execCommand("ds_format_edit_1");
    },
});

editor.addCommand('ds_format_edit_1', function (ed) {
    //do something
});
```

How can I set the visibility of my button via code?

I know there is a function "visible" for buttons but I dont know how to use it. 
The documentation confuses me. :/
Here the Link: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.ui.Control.visible

**Edit:**
Ok, I have created a dialog to create custom plugins. With this dialog the user have the chance to create new formatpatterns and he can set a shortcut. If he set a shortcut for his formatpattern I want to set the visibility of my button.
Here is a shortcut of my dialog:

[image]

The dialog is created with jQuery.
I hope this is a little bit clearer. :)

Thanks Felix

Comment: Die you try `visible: true,`  instead of `visible: false,` ?

Comment: I want to set the visibility of the button from an other postion of my code. And to set the visibility I need the button element.
Like this: editor.button("ds_format_edit_1").visible(true)  (pseudo-code)